# Unity: How to make Animation and Physics work together?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, physics

I'm beginner at Unity.

I downloaded asset with animations to check how animation controller and ragdoll is working. And then, I noticed, that when animation is playing, object stops reacting on physics and ragdoll, and when you switch off animation controller - physics starts working, as well as ragdoll.

Here is the video : https://youtu.be/_jjJal7F3Q4

So, question is: How to make physics working, while animation is playing? Like when I'm moving cubefrom under the persons feet - person, with animation, must fell down to the ground or other Collideble object.

Is the scripting necessary, or there any other solutions ?

Thank you!

Comment: See if you can find your answer here, it seems similar: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/468709/no-gravity-with-mecanim.html Let us know if you get it working, and what you did!

Comment: wrap animated objects inside an empty game object with a rigidbody and collider. this way you can handle smaller motions via animations while keeping the wrapper available to physics behaviours. but first make sure you understand IK.

Comment: @Bijan , thx! Nice idea, I'l check IK and try as you advised

Comment: @Fredrik , okay, sure, thx for helping!

Comment: @Fredrik , So I made like this: Added an empty object, with rigidbody and physics, and it's seemed to be working! ( Pretty creepy, but working! )
Here is the video : https://youtu.be/RHsL1mj95Mg

So now I gonna check IK.